# Why does Julia round integer division so much?

Tags: rounding, julia

Why does Julia give the following result

```
> 999731/1000000 
  1.00
```

instead of 0.999731? I've looked at a lot of documentation but I haven't seen how to fix this yet. I'm sure it's something simple with syntax that I missed.

```
Julia Version 0.5.0
Commit 3c9d753 (2016-09-19 18:14 UTC)

Platform Info:
  System: NT (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5300U CPU @ 2.30GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  BLAS: libopenblas (USE64BITINT DYNAMIC_ARCH NO_AFFINITY Haswell)
  LAPACK: libopenblas64_
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-3.7.1 (ORCJIT, broadwell)
```

Comment: Weird. I don't get that on either v0.4 or v0.5. Try `println(999731/1000000)`. Possibly you have some weird display setting in the REPL?

Comment: It was in the repl, but when I use println instead of the raw division, it shows the right values.

Comment: Yep, that's it. Somehow you've changed the default REPL display settings. Julia is still calculating the correct number, it is just *displaying* it rounded to 3 significant figures. I'm afraid I have no idea how to change those settings back to default values, and the first page of google results didn't look promising. Maybe ask at the new Discourse forum on the Julia homepage.

Comment: download and reinstall Julia

Comment: Updating Julia is probably the best answer. It is a moving target. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there's ever been a version of julia that did this natively. Check your `~/.juliarc.jl` file and your environment variables; you may be modifying some setting that affects printing by default on startup. You can also start julia as `julia --startup-file=no` and it will start a session without any startup file.